# Hook different functions to the same filter conditionally OR Pass additional arguments to existing filter?

Tags: filters

Is it possible to hook 3 different functions to the same filter conditionally, like:

```
<?php
if(a){
    add_filter('the_content', 'fnc_1');
}
else if(b){
    add_filter('the_content', 'fnc_2');
}
else{
    add_filter('the_content', 'fnc_3');
}
?>
```

Or if this isn't possible, then can I pass an additional argument to the same function to flag my 3 different conditions? Something like:

```
<?php
if(a){
    add_filter('the_content', 'fnc_1', 'condition_a');
}
else if(b){
    add_filter('the_content', 'fnc_1', 'condition_b');
}
else{
    add_filter('the_content', 'fnc_1', 'condition_c');
}
?>
```

All I could find from my reading is that it has to do something with `apply_filters`, but couldn't get around it.

Please can anyone tell me how to achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Method 1 is completely valid. Have you tried it yourself? Method 2 will not work, since [`add_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) does not allow you to pass additional arguments.

Comment: For method 2, you can wrap a custom filter over a defined filter and conditionally have it pass a second argument, I think. But I don't see any reason to other than for education.

Comment: Know a place where I can see an example? Like a blog or a tut?

Comment: Education it is then... check my answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it does appear to be an interesting question, I'll go ahead an compile an answer.

### Method 1

Totally fine, will work. Here's the compact piece of code I used to test it:

```
function fnc_1( $content ) { return 'func1 :: '.$content;   }
function fnc_2( $content ) { return 'func2 :: '.$content;   }
function fnc_3( $content ) { return 'func3 :: '.$content;   }

$a = false;
$b = false;

if ( $a ) add_filter( 'the_content', 'fnc_1' );
elseif ( $b ) add_filter( 'the_content', 'fnc_2' );
else add_filter( 'the_content', 'fnc_3' );
```

### Method 2

[`add_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) does not allow you to pass additional arguments to the filter function, but if you really need to share one function you can wrap a custom filter around the filter like so:

```
add_filter( 'wpse31470_filter_wrapper', 'wpse31470_filter_wrapper_func', null, 2 );

function wpse31470_filter_wrapper_func( $content, $condition ) {
    if ( $condition ) return 'TRUE :: '.$content;
    else return 'FALSE ::'.$content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse31470_the_content_filter' );
function wpse31470_the_content_filter( $content ) {
    $condition = true;
    return apply_filters( 'wpse31470_filter_wrapper', $content, $condition );
}
```

The purpose of the `wpse31470_the_content_filter` is to wrap the argument supplied by `the_content` filter and pass it on to your own `wpse31470_filter_wrapper` along with any additional arguments.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot... I'm trying the 2nd `apply_filters` method right away, cause if it works, many of my workarounds will go away! +1!

Comment: Yes indeed! If I stumble, I won't hesitate to ask you! And there goes the 'accept' ;)